# 301 htaccess redirects with 3 parameters to static urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Im trying to redirect several urls with 3 parameters to different static urls with .htaccess but nothing working.

1.

```
http://olddomain.com/index.php?id_category=28&controller=category&id_lang=2
```

to

```
https://newdomain.com/page1/
```

2. 

```
http://olddomain.com/index.php?id_category=30&controller=category&id_lang=2
```

to

```
https://newdomain.com/page2/
```

3. 

```
http://olddomain.com/index.php
```

to

```
https://newdomain.com
```

I tried the below code but http://olddomain.com/index.php not going to https://newdomain.com :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC] 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_category=28&controller=category&id_lang=2$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ https://newdomain.com/page1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_category=30&controller=category&id_lang=2$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ https://newdomain.com/page2/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your code. How are you passing category value to rewrite URL to index.php file? Kindly elaborate on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have specific longer matches first and then have rules to remove `index.php` or domain redirect:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# specific redirects with index.php as optional match
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_category=28&controller=category&id_lang=2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ https://newdomain.com/page1/? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_category=30&controller=category&id_lang=2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ https://newdomain.com/page2/? [R=301,L,NC]

# remove index.php and redirect to newdmain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php/?)?(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are taking page's id from id_lang= variable then please try following rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rules to redirect to link: https://newdomain.com/page1/ here.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?id_category=28&controller=category&id_lang=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com/page%1/? [NE,R=301,L]

##Rules to redirect https://newdomain.com/ here.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.com [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: well the below code is working and redirects the categories to new pages. but cant redirect the front page http://olddomain.com to https://newdomain.com and http://olddomain.com/index.php to https://newdomain.com                                                                                                    
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_category=28&controller=category&id_lang=2$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ https://newdomain.com/page1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id_category=30&controller=category&id_lang=2$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ https://newdomain.com/page2/? [R=301,L]

Comment: @Chris, could you please do let me know if my solution has worked for you? Thank you.

Comment: Actually this rule cannot be based on `id_lang=` parameter because it is `2` in both cases as per OP.